# Index matching from CsvHelper doesn't work

Tags: c#, csv

I use CSVHelper version 3 Beta 6:

CustomCsvMapping class:

```
public class FoobarCsvMapping : CsvClassMap<FooImportModel>
{
        public FoobarCsvMapping ()
        {
            Map(x => x.Foo).Index(0);
            ...
        }
}
```

And I configurate this custom mapping class by calling:

```
 reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new FoobarCsvMapping());
```

Structure of my testCsv file (1 line includes the header):

```
OtherHeaderPropertyName;...
0;...
```

If I read my csv-file, I always get the exception of type **CsvMissingFieldException** with this message:

> Fields 'Foo' do not exist in the CSV file.

I don't care about the header names in the csv-file, I want an index matching...

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think there is more that is missing here... Do you have the delimiter set to `;`? What other fields are mapped? I believe it's a different property that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`CsvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;`